# select row whith insert query - sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have two table (table1,table2)

```
table1 - table1_seq PK identity(1,1),
         table1_descpt

table2 - table2_seq PK identity(1,1),
         table1_seq foreign key of table1,
         table2_descpt
```

i want `table1_seq` same time when `insert into table1(table1_desc) values ('Description');`

**like** `select table1_seq from  (insert into table1(table1_desc) values ('Description'));`

so i can insert `table1_seq` into table2

Comment: read about the output clause.

Comment: Sounds like a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table1(table1_desc) OUTPUT inserted.table1_seq 
VALUES ('Description')
```

[Implementing the OUTPUT Clause in SQL Server 2008](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/implementing-the-output-clause-in-sql-server-2008/)

**SELECT @@IDENTITY**

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection, regardless of the table that produced the value, and regardless of the scope of the statement that produced the value.

**SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()**

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection and by a
>   statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the
>   value.

**SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)**

> It returns the last IDENTITY value produced in a table, regardless of
>   the connection that created the value, and regardless of the scope of
>   the statement that produced the value.

[SQL SERVER – @@IDENTITY vs SCOPE_IDENTITY() vs IDENT_CURRENT – Retrieve Last Inserted Identity of Record](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

to retrieve the [last identity value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms187342%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) that was generated in the current session by an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement.